# Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) error

Tags: php, localhost

I am trying to install my php script on live server but am getting an error. I have already created a db/user and uploaded sql to my phypmyadmin

Error I am getting is

> Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply telling you that the username or password is not right, so you can't have an access.

Please check the password and the name of the user inside your php script, take a look at this.

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
?>
```

You see in your case you need to change these parameters to the ones in your live server.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("your_server","your_user","your_password","your_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @WardNsour i will try this out and see if it works

Comment: And please check in the admin panel the users section what privilege's the users have and what users exist

Comment: i have checked all these, i even created a new user with a new db and changed password, granted all privileges but still the same error